# SQL add multiple "Count" together

Tags: sql

I'm trying to add the counts together and output the one with the max counts.

The question is: Display the person with the most medals (gold as place = 1, silver as place = 2, bronze as place = 3)

Add all the medals together and display the person with the most medals

Below is the code I have thought about (obviously doesn't work)

Any ideas?

```
Select cm.Givenname, cm.Familyname, count(*)
FROM Competitors cm JOIN Results re ON cm.competitornum = re.competitornum
WHERE re.place between '1' and '3'
group by cm.Givenname, cm.Familyname
having max (count(re.place = 1) + count(re.place = 2) + count(re.place = 3))
```

Sorry forgot to add that were not allowed to use ORDER BY.

Some data in the table

Competitors Table

```
Competitornum   GivenName   Familyname  gender  Dateofbirth Countrycode
219153          Imri        Daniel      Male    1988-02-02  Aus
```

Results Table

```
Eventid Competitornum   Place   Lane    Elapsedtime
SWM111  219153          1       2       20          02
```

Comment: Which RDBMS system are you using? Is it MSSQL Server?

Comment: erm it's just a normal sql thing..
I'm using sqlfire.

Comment: pretty much a database file to run in sqlfire, and write codes in sql to run and excute in sqlfire to display the outputs inside that database file..... if that actually makes any sense..

Comment: I'd guess if you just ordered by count(*) desc, and picked the top 1, you'd be golden.  - Best, David

Comment: sorry I forgot to add in the question that were not allowed to use Order By..

Comment: @Tuzki can you include the schema of your tables?

Comment: as in.. some data in that table? sure ill edit the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've described it sounds like you just need to take the "Top" individual in the total medal count. In order to do that you would write something like this.

```
Select top 1 cm.Givenname, cm.Familyname, count(*)
FROM Competitors cm JOIN Results re ON cm.competitornum = re.competitornum
WHERE re.place between '1' and '3'
group by cm.Givenname, cm.Familyname
order by count(*) desc
```

Without using order by you have a couple of other options though I'm glossing over whatever syntax peculiarities sqlfire may use.

You could determine the max medal count of any user and then only select competitors that have that count. You could do this by saving it out to a variable or using a subquery.

```
Select cm.Givenname, cm.Familyname, count(*)
FROM Competitors cm JOIN Results re ON cm.competitornum = re.competitornum
WHERE re.place between '1' and '3'
group by cm.Givenname, cm.Familyname
having count(*) = (    
    Select max( count(*) )
    FROM Competitors cm JOIN Results re ON cm.competitornum = re.competitornum
    WHERE re.place between '1' and '3'
    group by cm.Givenname, cm.Familyname
)
```

Just a note here. This second method is highly inefficient because we recalculate the max medal count for every row in the parent table. If sqlfire supports it you would be much better served by calculating this ahead of time, storing it in a variable and using that in the HAVING clause.

Comment: "aggregated nests are not allowed" as stated in sqlfire

Comment: @Tuzki - Perhaps JW's answer will work better for you? Without an install of sqlfire to test on it's difficult to tell what it will allow.

Comment: @john Woo's answer gave me an error: "INVALID EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST (NOT CONTAINED IN EITHER AN AGGREGATE FUNCTION OR THE GROUP BY LIST)

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by `re.place`, is that what you want? You want the results per ... ? :)

[edit] Good, now that's fixed you're almost there :)

The having is not needed in this case, you simply need to add a `count(re.EventID)` to your select and make a subquery out of it with a `max(that_count_column)`.

Comment: sorry that's not i want.. i want to group by the name.